# Combining Shapefiles with # of rows based on a matching column

Tags: gis, shapefile, arcmap

I'm used to working in ArcMap, and am trying to translate an analysis into R.

I have 4 shapefiles that represent 4 assessment parameters. Each shapefile has a unique column called Parameter_Score. Each shapefile also has a column with the Parcel_ID associated with that pixel. Each shapefile has a different number of rows because each parameter affected certain parcels differently, and thus has different Parcels listed.

I would like to create one shapefile that has the Parcel_ID information, as well as each Parameter's unique score. My problem is that the shapefiles all have a different number of elements. I'd like to merge them all together based on the Parcel_ID, and have values of 0 populate the scores for Parcels that are not included in a certain parameter.

For example, I'd like to take these two shapefiles:

[image]

and create a new shapefile/merge them into this:

[image: desired output]

I've looked into merge, join, etc, but none of them allow me to match Parcels that match and add 0 values to parcels that don't match. Instead, rows are either deleted, or all the second parameter's values are turned to 0. Does someone know of a function that can do what I'm asking? Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Was looking at this and just noticed that it *might* be an R question, even though it is not tagged as such. That seems to be what the text says.

There are lots of ways to do this in R, with powerful flexible packages like `data.table` or `dplyr`. But it is easy just using base-R too:

```
s1 <- data.frame(Parcel_ID=c(110,112,115,116),Score=c(1,2,3,4))
s2 <- data.frame(Parcel_ID=c(110,112,234,235),Score=c(5,6,7,8))

s3 <- merge(s1,s2,by="Parcel_ID",all=TRUE)
s3[is.na(s3)] <- 0
s3
```

Yielding:

```
  Parcel_ID Score.x Score.y
1       110       1       5
2       112       2       6
3       115       3       0
4       116       4       0
5       234       0       7
6       235       0       8
```